# Do i need to declare property in India when living in USA

Tags: united-states, india, real-estate

I have been living in US and paying taxes, filing FBAR to declare the foreign bank accounts. My question - do i also need to declare my property like the house in which parents are living (but its in my name) or a house that my wife has back home and her sister is currently living in that?

Comment: You do not specifically declare the property, but the fair market value of the property in FBAR.